# batch rename folder deleting trailing characters

Tags: bash, directory, rename

I have a lot of directory that end with "_ and 6 digits", eg:

```
diff_gb_and_pf_2voids_158543
```

I would like to find all that folders in the current folder, and rename them by deleting the "_" and the 6 digits at the end.

So far I'm stuck with this command:

```
find . -type d -print |grep '.*[0-9]\{6\}$' |xargs -I {} bash -c 'for i in {}; do mv "$i" ????; done;'
```

I can't find how to do the last step. I would try and call sed, but how ?
Also, if there is a nicer way, please tell.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using your shell:

```
for i in $(find . -mindepth 1 -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*_[0-9]{6}'); do 
    mv "$i" "${i%_*}";
done
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks. Could you just explain the "${i%_*}" please ?

Comment: @Napseis: Sure. This is bash parameter substitution, that removes the shortest rear pattern (`_*`) from the variable. The summary table on [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html) page may be worth a look. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
find /path -regex '.*_[0-9]\{6\}' -exec sh -c 'n="{}"; echo mv "{}" "${n%_*}"' \;
```

Check the output, if it looks good then drop the `echo` in there.

Explanation: for each matched file, we run a sub-shell, where we assign the filename to variable `n`, so that we can use pattern substitution `${n%_*}`, which cuts off the last `_` character and everything after it until the end of the filename.

Or here's a more portable way that should work in older systems too:

```
find /path -name '*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' | sed -ne 's/\(.*\)_[0-9]\{6\}$/mv "&" "\1"/p'
```

Check the output, if it looks good than pipe it to `sh` (append this: `| sh`)

Explanation:

1. The `sed` command receives the list of files to rename
2. In the pattern we capture the first part of the filename within `\( ... \)`
3. We replace the pattern with the text `mv "&" "\1"`, where `&` is substituted with the pattern that was matched, in this case the entire original filename, and `\1` is substituted with the part we captured within `\( ... \)`

Comment: the first one doesn't work on my shell, but the second one does. This also works
    find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*_[0-9]{6}'  | sed -ne 's/\(.*\)_[0-9]\{6\}$/mv "&" "\1"/p'
But I don't understand that part, could you explain please ?:
    mv "&" "\1"/p

Comment: I added explanation for both the `sed` part, and the `${n%_*}` in the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

ls -d diff* > dirlist

while IFS='_' read field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6
do
mv -v "${field1}_${field2}_${field3}_${field4}_${field5}_${field6}" \
"${field1}_${field2}_${field3}_${field4}_${field5}"
done < dirlist
```